# How to find $\dim W_1$, $\dim W_2$, $\dim W_1+W_2$, $\dim W_1\cap W_2$ for the following spans?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

Let $W_1=\{(1,1,2,1), (3,1,0,0)\}$ and $W_2=\{(-1,-2,0,1), (-4,-2,-2,-1)\}$

Apparently $\dim W_1=\dim W_2=2$.

For $\dim W_1\cap W_2$, since $(-4,-2,-2,-1)$ can be expressed as $-(1,1,2,1)-(3,1,0,0)$, $\dim W_1\cap W_2=1$. But what if the spans are complicated, how do you find $\dim W_1\cap W_2$. Do you try matrix on each vector and see which ones has a nontrivial solution?

For $\dim W_1+W_2$, how do you know it without calculating $\dim W_1\cap W_2$?

Comment: To be pedantic, I think it's important to note the difference between the set of two vectors, and the span of that set. Here $W_1$ isn't a vector space, but taking the span makes it a vector space. So it only makes sense to talk about the dimension of $\text{span} W_1$.

Answer (score 2):

Put the given vectors into the columns of matrices
\begin{align*}
w_1 &=
\left[\begin{array}{rr}
1 & 3 \\
1 & 1 \\
2 & 0 \\
1 & 0
\end{array}\right] &
w_2 &=
\left[\begin{array}{rr}
-1 & -4 \\
-2 & -2 \\
0 & -2 \\
1 & -1
\end{array}\right]
\end{align*}
The dimensions of $W_1$ and $W_2$ are the ranks of the matrices $w_1$ and $w_2$ respectively. Row reducing gives $\DeclareMathOperator{rref}{rref}$
\begin{align*}
\rref(w_1) &=
\left[\begin{array}{rr}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 \\
0 & 0
\end{array}\right]
&
\rref(w_2) &=
\left[\begin{array}{rr}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 \\
0 & 0
\end{array}\right]
\end{align*}
These reduced row-echelon forms show that both $w_1$ and $w_2$ have rank two. This proves that $\dim W_1=\dim W_2=2$, as you have observed.

Now, the dimension of $W_1+W_2$ is the rank of the matrix
$$
[w_1,w_2]
=
\left[\begin{array}{rrrr}
1 & 3 & -1 & -4 \\
1 & 1 & -2 & -2 \\
2 & 0 & 0 & -2 \\
1 & 0 & 1 & -1
\end{array}\right]
$$
Row reducing gives
$$
\rref[w_1,w_2]=
\left[\begin{array}{rrrr}
1 & 0 & 0 & -1 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & -1 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{array}\right]
$$
This proves that $\dim (W_1+W_2)=3$. The dimension formula then implies that $\dim(W_1\cap W_2)=1$.

This method also provides bases for the spaces in question. The pivot columns of $\rref[w_1,w_2]$ correspond to the columns in $[w_1,w_2]$ that form a basis for $W_1+W_2$. The "free" columns of $\rref[w_1,w_2]$ correspond to the columns of $[w_1,w_2]$ that span $W_1\cap W_2$. Here, we have $\DeclareMathOperator{Span}{Span}$
\begin{align*}
W_1+W_2 &=
\Span
\left\{
\left[\begin{array}{r}
1 \\
1 \\
2 \\
1
\end{array}\right],
\left[\begin{array}{r}
3 \\
1 \\
0 \\
0
\end{array}\right],
\left[\begin{array}{r}
-1 \\
-2 \\
0 \\
1
\end{array}\right]
\right\}
&
W_1\cap W_1
&= \Span\left\{
\left[\begin{array}{r}
-4 \\
-2 \\
-2 \\
-1
\end{array}\right]
\right\}
\end{align*}

Comment: The row reduction also shows the fourth vector is in the intersection of the two subspaces, so it makes a basis for the intersection. And that a basis for the sum consists of the first three vectors.

Comment: Correct. Updated!

Comment: Of course, you should mention that this method works only because $$(−4,−2,−2,−1) = \alpha (1,1,2,1) + \beta (3,1,0,0)$$

for some scalars $\alpha$ and $\beta$. If we had:
$$(−4,−2,−2,−1) = \alpha (1,1,2,1) + \beta (3,1,0,0) + \gamma(−1,−2,0,1) $$
for some $\gamma \ne 0$ then the desired vector in $W_1 \cap W_2$ would be $\alpha (1,1,2,1) + \beta (3,1,0,0)$, and not $(−4,−2,−2,−1)$. It seems to be confusing people.

Comment: @mechanodroid sir, i am solving similar type of problem with 6 column vectors. The method in above answer is very easy to find basis for $W_1\cap W_2$ but seems not working in case of my problem. In my problem, $dim(W_1\cap W_2)=2$. So sir isn't there is any easy method to find basis for $W_1\cap W_2$ if $dim(W_1\cap W_2)$ is large? I know the method, but it need too much calculations if dimension of $dim(W_1\cap W_2) >1$.

Comment: @AkashPatalwanshi That is probably because the above method doesn't work in general. Consider $W_1, W_2 \le \mathbb{R}^4$ subspaces with bases $\left\{\begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}\right\}$ and $\left\{\begin{bmatrix}0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}\right\}$ respectively. Then the corresponding matrix is $$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}$$
which is already in row echelon form.

Comment: @AkashPatalwanshi The above answer claims that the basis for $W_1 \cap W_2$ is given by $$\left\{\begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}\right\}$$
which is false since this vector is not in $W_1$. The correct basis should be for example 
$$\left\{\begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}\right\}$$