# To find basis of intersection of two subspaces.

Tags: linear-algebra

$W_1$ and $W_2$ are subspaces of $R^{4}$ spanned by $[{(1,2,3,4),(2,1,1,2)]}$ and $[(1,0,1,0),(3,0,1,0)]$ respectively.Question is to find basis of $W_1 \cap W_2$ and also basis of $W_1 + W_2$ containing $[{(1,0,1,0),(3,0,1,0)}]$.I find rref of matrix $A=\left[\begin{array}{cccc}1&3&1&2\\0&0&2&1\\1&1&3&1\\0&0&4&2\end{array}\right]$ which gives me rank of this matrix 3.So the span of first three columns of matrix $A$ forms basis of $W_1 + W_2$ and last column of matrix $A$ forms basis of $W_1 \cap W_2.$Have I done it correctly?I have one more doubt.Suppose If I calculate rref of $A=\left[\begin{array}{cccc}1&2&1&3\\2&1&0&0\\3&1&1&1\\4&2&0&0\end{array}\right]$,then in this case last column of matrix again the basis of $W_1 \cap W_2$.So,in first case basis of $W_1 \cap W_2$ was span{[2,1,1,2]} and in second case it is ${[3,0,1,0]}$.What is correct then?

Comment: I can't understand why you call that second matrix the rref of A: that second matrix isn't even in row echelon form...

Comment: No,I am saying that if I calculate rref of that matrix(I have interchanged the columns of first one)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You know that $W_1 + W_2 = \operatorname{span} (W_1 \cup W_2)$, so the set $$\{(1,0,1,0),(3,0,1,0), (1,2,3,4),(2,1,1,2)\}$$

certainly spans $W_1 + W_2$.

Also, $$(2,1,1,2) = -\frac32(1,0,1,0) + (3,0,1,0) + \frac12(1,2,3,4)$$

and $\{(1,0,1,0),(3,0,1,0), (1,2,3,4)\}$ is linearly independent so it is a basis for $W_1 + W_2$.

We have:

$$\dim (W_1 \cap W_2) = \dim W_1 + \dim W_2 - \dim (W_1 \cap W_2) = 1$$

so it suffices to find one nontrivial vector in $W_1 \cap W_2$. After inspection, we see that it is:

$$-\frac32(1,0,1,0) + (3,0,1,0) = \left(\frac32, 0, -\frac12, 0\right) = -\frac12 (1, 2, 3, 4) + (2, 1, 1, 2)$$

so $\left\{\left(\frac32, 0, -\frac12, 0\right)\right\}$ is a basis for $W_1 \cap W_2$. You can also take $\left\{\left(3, 0, -1, 0\right)\right\}$ as a basis to get rid of fractions.

Comment: Thanks.Is the two bases I derived for $W_1 \cap W_2$ are right?If right why do they both have same span?

Comment: @omkarGirkar No, neither of them is correct. $W_1 \cap W_2$ is the subspace spanned by $(3, 0, -1, 0)$, so any basis for $W_1 \cap W_2$ must be a multiple of $(3, 0, -1, 0)$. Your method for finding the basis for $W_1 \cap W_2$ does not seem correct, as vectors in $W_1 \cap W_2$ are the ones in $W_1$ and in $W_2$. Taking the last column gives you a vector only in $W_2$, or $W_1$ in the second case.

Comment: I used method described in this answer.https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1648036/how-to-find-dim-w-1-dim-w-2-dim-w-1w-2-dim-w-1-cap-w-2-for-the-f

Comment: What's wrong going on.Please help.

Comment: @omkarGirkar Let $W_1 = \operatorname{span}\{a, b\}$, $W_2  = \operatorname{span}\{c, d\}$. You concluded that the first three vectors $\{a, b, c\}$ are linearly independent, and that $d = \alpha a + \beta b + \gamma c$ for some scalars $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$. In the specific case you linked they had $\gamma = 0$, so $d = \alpha a + \beta b$, which implies $d \in W_1 \cap W_2$. But in general, you cannot conclude that. You have $d = \alpha a + \beta b + \gamma c$ so rearranging gives $\alpha a + \beta b = -\gamma c + d$, so $\alpha a + \beta b$ is the desired vector in $W_1 \cap W_2$.

Comment: So basically, the method in that answer relies on additional properties which do not hold in general. I have left a comment at that answer about the issue.

Comment: @omkarGirkar Also, be careful, the fact that the rank of the matrix is $3$ does not imply that the first $3$ columns are independent. It could be any $3$ columns. You have to additionally verify it, for example by calculating the rref and noticing that the first three columns are themselves linearly independent.